# Context menu events not working in QOpenGLWindow

Tags: qt, qwidget, qwindow

I am subclassing `QOpenGLWindow` (not `QGLWidget` or `QOpenGLWidget`) and calling

```
auto container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(my_opengl_window);
```

to place it in the layout of a parent `QWidget`.

The window displays correctly and I can interact with it, but `container` (and its parent widget) do not receive context menu events when I right-click within `my_opengl_window`. I do get a context menu if I right-click on the slim margin between the window and its container.

```
void MyGLWindow::mousePressEvent (QMouseEvent * e)
{
    qDebug (__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    QOpenGLWindow::mousePressEvent (e);
}
```

The above shows me that `my_opengl_window` is receiving mouse clicks. I have also tried `e->ignore ()` but still the parent does not receive a context menu event.

Also, `setCursor` and `setToolTip` on the container widget have no effect. I suspect this may be related.

How can I get these mouse events to work on a `QOpenGLWindow` container?

Comment: How are you checking for context menu events in the `QOpenGLWindow`?  As far as I know `QOpenGLWindow` just doesn't generate/handle `QContextMenuEvent` at all.

Comment: As far as ***I*** know, `QOpenGLWindow` just doesn't generate/handle `QContextMenuEvent` at all, but I can't see that this is documented.

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand that last comment.  Why would they document functionality that *isn't* there?  `QWidget` has the [`QWidget::contextMenuEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuEvent) member, `QOpenGLWindow` doesn't.  I think it's simply the case that you have to create/show the menu yourself on a right mouse button press or click.

Comment: Because I want the *containing* `QWidget` to have a context menu event, *like normal*. Clicks are still being detected on the widget, but the context menu event is somehow being suppressed and I can't see a reason why.